# SSIS - additional installed task doesn`t appear

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I've installed additional task to Control Flow in VS 2012 (SSIS). It should appear in common sub menu in SSIS Toolbox. Unfortunately it doesn't and I`ve tried to refresh toolbox, restart server, and also in tools -> choose toolbox items and can`t see the control flow menu.

Comment: What did you install? Are you certain you installed a version that corresponds to SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Yes, I`m sure because on my private pc it works. I downloaded install file from this site:https://ssisexcelrefresh.codeplex.com.

Comment: [SSISExcelRefresh](https://ssisexcelrefresh.codeplex.com/discussions/586989#post1364347) only works for SQL Server 2012 SSIS packages which are authored with [Visual Studio 2010](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAOHg.png) *or* [Visual Studio 2012](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLMGh.png). If you click Help, About and don't see Version 10 or Version 11 listed, you have the wrong version of the SSIS editor installed.